# Adding common parameters to different apis in retrofit2

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

I have 10+ different apis right now, and I want to add some common request parameters per api, the ideal way is having interceptors per api, which is impossible in retrofit.
Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to do this with retrofit - create a class with a static creation for the API call and call the extensions you need based on the parameters passed.

```
public interface RetrofitAPICalls{
}

public class RetrofitAPIService{
      private RetroFitAPIService(){}
      public static RetrofitAPICalls createApiService(PARAMETERS NEEDED FOR YOUR INTERCEPTOR){
             Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl);

             OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(getInterceptor()).addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
               .build();
            builder.client(client);
       }
}
public void getInterceptor()
{
     return new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Request newReq = request.newBuilder()

                    //SWITCH BASED ON REQUEST?

                   return chain.proceed(newReq);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does that mean per retrofit and okhttp per api? I thought that would be bad because retrofit is pretty heavy to create, 10+ apis would be 10+ retrofit client

Comment: I modified my original answer - I see what you're saying and that's not really what I meant, but if you extract the interceptor you can swtich on the request in some way and add the headers per header. That would be able to leverage a single Retro/OkHttp client while being extended to handle your multiple use cases. It's definitely not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, that's what I was doing, but as you said, it's not ideal since you need a way to identify different requests and then modify it. I believe this is a fairly common need, still wondering if there is better way to do it